# How can I get value from react modal bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

How can I get value from bootstrap modal? I'm using `reacstrap`  https://github.com/reactstrap

Here is my page that call the modal

```
import { ButtonGroup, Button, Input, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import RegisterLookup from '../lookup/RegisterLookup';

<RegisterLookup
  isOpen={this.state.register}
  toggle={this.toggleRegister}
  className={''}
/>
```

and here is my modal component:

```
  register() {
    console.log("da")
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} toggle={this.props.toggle} className={this.props.className} size="lg">
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggle}>Register</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <Row>
                  <Col md="6" xs="12">
                    <FormGroup row>
                      <Label sm="4">Enter your name <span className="text-danger">*</span></Label>
                      <Col>
                        <Input />
                      </Col>
                    </FormGroup>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            </div>

          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button className="pull-right" type="button" color="primary" onClick={() => { this.register(); }}>
              <span className="hidden-xs-down">Register </span>
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

RegisterLookup.defaultProps = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  toggle: PropTypes.func,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

RegisterLookup.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  toggle: PropTypes.func,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};
```

It show the modal : 
[image]

but how can I get the value I enter in modal to my page that call the modal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send the value back with a function you send as a prop from the parent to the modal.

Here's an example that I have simplified to highlight the changes you need to make. The Modal controls the state of the `Input` but when you hit the button the local `reg()` function is called, which in turn calls the `register()` function from the parent because it's being passed down as a prop called `onRegister`. We pass `name` as the argument to that function call.

Note that I've also added the `nameChange()` function which you didn't have. This function is called whenever the value of the `Input` is changed (e.g by a keypress) and updates the local `state`.

---

**Parent:**

```
register(name) {
  console.log(name);
}


render() {
  return(
    <RegisterLookup onRegister={this.register} />
  );
}
```

**Modal:**

```
nameChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({name: e.target.value});
}

reg = () => {
  this.props.onRegister(this.state.name);
}

render() {
  return(
    <Modal>
      Enter your name: <Input onChange={this.nameChange} />
      <Button onClick={this.reg}>Register</Button>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```