# How to insert URL into text area using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textbox

I have made a small modal pop-up for getting the URL from the user. I want to insert that URL into a textbox in ReactJS. I can't figure out how to add that URL into the text area.

Comment: please show some code or go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need a state variable for that textbox and then calling `setState` to set the URL value to the textbox. It's basic React, please see how to use State here: https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/#state

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

Use local state to achieve this. For example take url as input from user and set it into local state and use that state in modal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
[How can I get value from react modal bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406350/how-can-i-get-value-from-react-modal-bootstrap)

Get the value from the modal as mentioned above, store it, and then display that stored value in the textbox.

```
<textbox value= { nameOfVariable }></textbox>
```